# Using ruby to make a class active via helper method - error in variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been having problems with my coffeescript, so instead I would like to use ruby to make my classes active in the view when clicked.  I created a helper method called nav "active", and I have a variable called 'link' in the view that increments up for each step.   The idea is to have params[:id] == link , and make the class active when that is the case .  However, being newer to rails and ruby I am not sure how to implement this.  Any help would be appreciated.

My error

```
 undefined local variable or method `link' for #<#<Class:0x007fb21e087820>:0x007fb21e53fd18>
```

My Method in application helper

```
    def nav_active(options = {})

      return "active" if params[:id] == link

    end
```

My view

```
     <% icon= ["icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit", "icon-beaker","icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit", "icon-beaker"] %>
    <% link = 0 %>

    <% @step_list.each_with_index do |step, i| %>

    <% case step.media_type %>
    <% when 'video' %>
     <% link += 1 %>
             <li class="<%= nav_active %>">
               <span class="glow"></span>
               <a href="<%= link %>">
                  <i class='icon-info-sign icon-2x'></i>
                  <span>Video</span>
               </a>
             </li>


<% when 'excel' %>
<% link += 1 %>
        <li class="<%= nav_active %>">
          <span class="glow"></span>
          <a href="<%= link %>">
              <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i>
              <span>Step <%= i %> </span>
          </a>
        </li>

<% else %>
<% link += 1 %>
        <li class="dark-nav <%= nav_active %> ">
          <span class="glow"></span>
         <a href="<%= link %>">
              <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i>
              <span>Step <%= i %></span>
          </a>
        </li>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper method `nav_active` doesn't have access to the local variables in your view.  You have to pass that in as an argument.

```
# Helper
def nav_active(link)
  return "active" if params[:id] == link
end
```

This helper now accepts an argument named `link`.  Now `link` will be defined in the helper method.

```
<% link += 1 %>
<li class="dark-nav <%= nav_active link %> ">
```

In the view you also must also pass in the current value of link, so the helper method can operate on it.

Comment: hmm this got rid of the error, and it allows the link to be passing through, but does not actually send "active" when the link is active.  I am not sure if it something wrong with params[:id] - this is my  Parameters: {"course_id"=>"1", "level_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}

Comment: This may be because `link` is a number and `params[:id]` is a string.  So try forcing them both to strings. `if params[:id].to_s == link.to_s`